# Repeating image in a path with smaller to bigger effects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I recently started studying Illustrator and I just would like to ask how can I do a pattern similar to the image below

[image: Sample]

I am looking at the STAR, and I just would like to ask how to create that effects from small to big.  And it seems that it is on a path.

I only rely on using the net for teaching myself so I do not have any formal training.

This is my first post so please be gentle if my question is very novice. :)

Hope the community would accept newbie wannabe designer's like me.
Thanks

Comment: While it is technically possible to put these on a so-called scatter brush in Illustrator, you'd have better control over both size and position of the smaller stars just by copying, reszing and rotating.

Comment: Just as a resource, this is a website I used to use YEARS ago to play about with and practice different tips and tricks on all adobe products: http://www.good-tutorials.com/tutorials/illustrator Good Luck! PS. Change your username, just make it more "you" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blends are the easiest.

You need a starting object, an ending objects, then create the blend (`Object > Blend > Make`) Then draw the path you want the steps to follow. Select the blend and the new path and choose `Object > Blend > Replace Spine`.

There are other ways depending upon what you are after, such as symbols, brushes, patterns, etc. However, blends often work pretty well in many instances.

Comment: Haven't reach this far in my reading but it seems like what I needed.  Thanks for this. I will explore this first then try it out.  Thanks